# OpenShift template "object already exists" error

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have developed an Openshift template which basically creates two objects (A cluster & a container operator).

I understand that templates run `oc create` under the hood. So, in case any of these two objects already exists then trying to create the objects through template would through an error. Is there any way to override this behaviour? I want my template to re-configure the object even if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "oc process" which renders template into set of manifests:

```
oc process foo PARAM1=VALUE1 PARAM2=VALUE2 | oc apply -f -
```

or

```
oc process -f template.json PARAM1=VALUE1 PARAM2=VALUE2 | oc apply -f -
```

Comment: Works perfectly from CLI. Any equivalent solution for running template from OpenShift Web UI?

Comment: No, I don't think so.